# Integral of $\sin^5(x)\cos(x)$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, indefinite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

I'm trying to solve the following integral:

$$\int\sin^5(x)\cos(x)$$

I assumed I would do u-substitution where:

$$u = \sin(x)$$

$$du = \cos(x) dx$$

Which would then cancel out the $\cos(x)$

And leave me with:

$$\int u^5 du = \frac{u^6}{6} +C = \frac{\sin^6(x)}{6} + C$$

But apparently that is not correct?

**Update**: Seems it is the correct answer. The system I was using gave a different answer, so I plugged in a value into both the system's answer and my own answer, and got different results. Not sure why, but you can consider this closed then.

Comment: $+C$ you forgot

Comment: What do you mean, "it's not correct?" Did you follow all the instructions your online homework system (coughcough Webassign) gave you?

Comment: This is *fully* correct. Actually no substitution is needed, because this is in the form $\int g'(f(x))f'(x)\,dx=g(f(x))+c$, with $g(x)=x^6/6$ and $f(x)=\sin x$.

Comment: @SeanRoberson So the answer they gave is in a different form, and I tried plugging in a value into their answer, and a value into my answer, and I got different results. So I assumed they weren't the same but I guess they are.

Comment: If differentiating the two solutions gives back $\sin^5x\cos x$, then *both* are correct.

Comment: @egreg That's a better way to check it, thank you.

Comment: what is the give answer? many computer programs use complex exponential properties to calculate integrals of this type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your answer is correct.

Note that by using a different integration method you can get an answer which **looks different** but it is not.

For example
$$\int\sin^5(x)\cos(x)=\int\sin(x) (1-\cos^2(x))^2 \cos(x) dx$$can becalculayted using the substitution $v=\cos(x)$. If you do this, the answer loos different, but that's just an illusion.

Same way, you can use 
$$\sin^5(x)\cos(x)=\left(\frac{1-\cos(2x)}{2}\right)^2\frac{\sin(2x)}{2}$$
and then the substitution $u=\cos(2x)$.